# YouTube API: video privacy option

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How can I set a privacy option for the uploaded video? In the documentation I've found only http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:private, but how can I mark video as "Unlisted"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have experience with this API, but it looks like

```
<yt:accessControl action='list' permission='denied'/>
```

is what you are after. This tag is mentioned on the same page that you linked to,

http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:accessControl

Hope this helps, and please give some indication whether this suits your needs.

Answer (score 4):

if you guys are doing this in PHP with Zend Gdata this is how its done:

```
// create a new video
$video = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();
$video->setVideoTitle('My Test Movie');
$video->setVideoDescription('My Test Movie');
$video->setVideoCategory('Animals');
$video->SetVideoTags('tag1, tag2');

// make video unlisted
$unlisted = new Zend_Gdata_App_Extension_Element('yt:accessControl', 'yt', 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007', '');
$unlisted->setExtensionAttributes(array(
    array('namespaceUri' => '', 'name' => 'action', 'value' => 'list'),
    array('namespaceUri' => '', 'name' => 'permission', 'value' => 'denied')
));
$video->setExtensionElements(array($unlisted));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using any of the existing libraries (e.g., when implementing via Classic ASP), add the

```
<yt:accessControl action="list" permission="denied" />
```

in between the `<entry></entry>` pair. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
    <media:group>
        <media:title type="plain">Video Title Here</media:title>
        <media:description type="plain">Video Description Here</media:description>
        <media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">Person</media:category>
        <media:keywords>Video Keywords Here</media:keywords>
    </media:group>
    <yt:accessControl action="list" permission="denied" />
</entry>
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_updating_and_deleting_videos